# How to use Rails routing without resources, with use only ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, filtering

**Description.**

I want filtering product on my site, but I won't use nested resources.

Filtering has 4 level.

For example,

https://example.com/london/car/bmw/red

or

https://example.com/:city/:category/:brand/:color

routes.rb

```
get '/:one_id', to: 'categories#show', as: 'category_one'
get '/:one_id/:two_id', to: 'categories#show', as: 'category_two'
get '/:one_id/:two_id/:three_id', to: 'categories#show', as: 'category_three'
get '/:one_id/:two_id/:three_id/:four_id', to: 'categories#show', as: 'category_four'
```

Why I use names id like ":one_id", ":two_id" etc.?

Because ": one_id" may contain multiple objects (filters).

For example,

https://example.com/london/

https://example.com/bmw/

https://example.com/woman/

i.e, ":one_id" may be city, category or sex (multiple entity) and ":two_id" may be category, brand or color, etc.

**Question:**

What are the best practices for organizing such routing?

**Configuration:**

Ruby 2.5.1

Rails 5.2.2.1

Comment: You're asking for best practices but say that you don't want to use the rails inbuilt system for routing which is their recommended method

Comment: Section 3 contains everything on non-resourceful routes - it's doable but it doesn't look pretty in comparison: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes

Comment: Thanks, @Mark. I understand that. But I have a specific task from real life.
This task has already been implemented using "bad" practices, but I know for sure there's a more correct way of implementation.
Rails are a very elastic platform.

Comment: They do say at the start of the guide that resourceful routes won't work for every application so you may well be right

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shallow` to avoid deep nesting resources in rails. You can read [this tutorial](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) to have more information.

Comment: Maybe. But :shallow option doesn't allow to completely abandon the use of the parent name in the url (/parent/:id). 
How can I organize my url like "/:id/:id/:id/:id" ?